# Can't find Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.SingleSignOn.dll on Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I'm trying to migrate across old code onto sharepoint 2010 where we utilize Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.SingleSignOn.dll. I can't seem to find the dll anywhere (14 folder, GAC, Visual Studio .Net reference dialog).

[MSDN seem to believe that the dll should still be available but doesn't specify where it is located.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.portal.singlesignon.aspx)

I have Sharepoint 2010 Server installed on my development environment with Server Farm setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Single Sign-On in Sharepoint 2010 is renamed to Secure Store Service.
And the DLL is using Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.dll.

Here's the KB from Microsoft on how you can reference that DLL:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982263

Cheers,

Z.